# Как зарегистрировать приложение в системе?

Tags: c#, .net

Как программно сделать так, чтобы устанавливаемое ПО добавилось в "Programs and Features"? Нашла информацию, что нужно сделать некоторые записи в реестре, но никакой конкретики.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно в "Programs and Features" регистрируются не программы, а их установщики. Сам раздел реестра находится по пути:

- 32 - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`
- 64 - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Для регистрации создаем раздел, название которого обычно берется `GUID` программы (можно и что то другое).
Далее в этом разделе создаем два обязательных строковых параметра:

- `DisplayName` - Имя программы.
- `UninstallString` - Путь до файла удаления.

Все, уже сейчас в разделе "Programs and Features" вы увидите свое приложение.
Для установки других значений (версии, иконки и др.) вы можете заглянуть в [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/uninstall-registry-key).

---

Теперь по поводу программного пути:
Тут пойдет простейшая работа с реестром.

1. Ищем ключ реестра (Uninstall):
   Обратите внимание на `true` в конце, это означает, что мы открываем ключ для чтения!

   ```
   var uninstallKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall", true);
   ```
2. Создаем раздел с названием нашей программы:

   ```
   var programKey = uninstallKey?.CreateSubKey("MyProgram");
   ```
3. Заполняем раздел данными и закрываем:

   ```
   programKey?.SetValue("DisplayName", "Super Program!");
   programKey?.SetValue("UninstallString", "C:\\Program.exe");
   programKey?.Close();
   ```

Все, после этого у нас появится новое приложение в "Programs and Features".
Заметьте, что для этого нужны права администратора!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Где хранить uninstaller.exe? Если он будет лежать в `Program Files/MyApp`, то он не сможет удалить эту директорию, ведь она используется в запущенном процессе (этот же uninstaller.exe). Я так поняла, его нужно ложить отдельно от всех остальных файлов? Если да, то куда. В одну директорию с остальными файлами приложения не положишь, ведь их тоже надо будет зачищать.

Comment: Помсотрела свой Registry - все деинсталяторы лежат в Program Files/MyApp. То есть они как-то удаляют директории, в которых находятся.

Comment: @J.Huxley Вы можете воспользоваться например вариантом удаления через консоль (что то вроде `Application.Current.Shutdown(); Process.Start("CMD.exe", $"/C RD /S /Q {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}");`), но как по мне лучше создать полноценный установщик, который и зарегистрирует приложение и создаст файл для удаления. Ну а вообще, это уже отдельный вопрос и советую вам его задать отдельно.